# TextView go off screen in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:rowOrderPreserved="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Test:" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="too long line too long line too long line too long line" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Test2:"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Test line" />
</GridLayout>
```

and here is the screenshot of what happens:

[image: TextView]

How can I prevent second TextView (the one selected on the screenshot) from going over screen boundaries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can avoid all of this by giving each textview a width of match_parent and an appropriate layout_weight. The below code will give you exactly what you need. Enjoy!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Test 1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="line too long line too long line too long line too long line too long "/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="Test 2"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="line too long line too long line too long line too long line too long "/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the right way to go, but the answer could be a little more elaborate, for example adding a code snippet showing a correct way to do it. Good solution though ;)

Comment: I apologize for that. Was in a bit of a rush, but wanted to help :)

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider: Thanks. Could you please post an example using layout_weight?

Comment: Answer edited to show code. Keep in mind that layout_weight MUST be used with match_parent. If the parent LinearLayout is orientation:horizontal, then layout_weight of the child will be applied to the width, and vice versa for vertical and layout_height.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is easy. Just 3 lines of XML code.
In your textview, place the following lines:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:width = "0dp"/>
```

Comment: Wow... After 2 days, you solved my problem… Setting scrollsbars, setting maxlines, setting singleline to false, setting weight. Everything didn't helped and the width was always double as the screen size. After setting the width (300dp is also ok), the line was wrapped to 2 lines! Thank you! Now I am asking me why this is the only way to wrap a textview to multiple lines (maybe because the text is changed programmatically?)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your textView width is wrap_content. So means if your text is too long then it will be out of screen.  So better way is to set it to **match_parent**.

And Yes if it is too long then you can set ***MaxLines*** for it.