# Too much of words make the words go out of the screen

Tags: android, user-interface, interface

The Description2 If I write too much of word. the word will go to outside of the screen. How to fix it?

[image]

This is one of my XML's code, I'm using table layout with TextView.

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="282dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Description2:"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDescription2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Description2 Here"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>
                </TableRow>
```

Is there anyway to make it keep showing at the bottom of the Description2? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782608/textview-go-off-screen-in-relativelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want long text for multi lines?
you can use this options.

***android:layout_weight***

```
<TableRow android:layout_width="282dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description2:"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDescription2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description2 Here"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>
            </TableRow>
```

insert to two textview, android:layout_weight 1, android:layout_weight 3. it will works.

I recommend this for you.

add this code in xml.

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

and select this textview in java code. because this work when focused.

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setSelected(true);
```

it display all text in single line. text moving slow.
this solution, length of text dosen't change UI.